# Getting an SQL column index based on the column name

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I need to be able to get the index of a column based on the name of the column in the metadata. Currently I have the following... It is a mix of JavaFX and JDBC code (see my comment in code for exactly what I'm trying to do)

```
String selectedTable = tablegroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString();
String primaryKey;
try{
    ResultSet primaryKeyRS = meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, selectedTable.toUpperCase());
    while (primaryKeyRS.next()){
    primaryKey = primaryKeyRS.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
    /*
    I want to do something like this:
    Int pkIndex = meta.getIndex(primaryKey);
    */
}
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does anybody know of a way that I can achieve this? I know that there is a function I could use like meta.getIndexInfo(args) but I'm not entirely understanding how I can use it to achieve what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Brendan , are you trying to extract the indexes that have been created on the table using the getIndexInfo() API ? , what is meant by PK Index ? Unique indexes created on the table ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the index of the primary key of the table. There are many tables in my database and I'm not sure how to use the getIndexInfo API, there is very little information that I can find. I figured that this is what I need to be using, and posted here in hopes that somebody could help me out. All that I really need to do is get the index of the primary key of a specific table.

Answer (score 0):

Use two JdbcRowSet objects and join between them:

```
String selectedTable = tablegroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString();
String primaryKey;
try{
    ResultSet primaryKeyRS = meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, selectedTable.toUpperCase());
    ResultSet indexInfoRS = meta.getIndexInfo(null, null, selectedTable.toUpperCase());

    JdbcRowSet pkRowSet = new JdbcRowSetImpl(primaryKeyRS);
    JdbcRowSet idxRowSet = new JdbcRowSetImpl(indexInfoRS);
    JoinRowSet joinRowSet = new JoinRowSetImpl();

    joinRowSet.setJoinType(JoinRowSet.INNER_JOIN);

    joinRowSet.addRowSet(pkRowSet, "COLUMN_NAME");
    joinRowSet.addRowSet(idxRowSet, "COLUMN_NAME");

    while(joinRowSet.next()) {
       System.out.println(joinRowSet.getString("INDEX_NAME"));
    }
}
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```